# using Identity Theorem for a proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disk  and let $f,g: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic functions and be continuous on $\overline {\mathbb{D}}$.
Show when $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \partial \mathbb{D} $, then $f \equiv g $.

I thought that because $f(z)-g(z)=0$ on $\partial \mathbb{D} $ you can find a sequence in $\mathbb{D}$ which converges against these $z\in \partial \mathbb{D} $. So by identity theorem it follows  $f \equiv g $.
 for $z\in \mathbb{D}$. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum modulus principle states that a holomorphic function takes its maximum on the boundary. So consider $h(z)=f(z)-g(z)$. We have, on $\partial\Bbb D$, $0\leq|h(z)|\leq0$, where the first inequality is by definition and the second inequality follows from $f(z)=g(z)$ on $\partial\Bbb D$. Thus $|h(z)|=0$ for all $z\in\Bbb D$. This means $h(z)=0$ for all $z\in\Bbb D$, giving $f(z)=g(z)$.

Comment: Just a question: Why can you conclude $|h(z)|=0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$? Isn't it for all $z\in \partial \mathbb{D}$?

Comment: @Thesinus: By the maximum modulus principle. Since $|h(z)|=0$ for all $z\in\partial\Bbb D$ (this is the maximum possible modulus...), it is true for all $z\in\Bbb D$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not apply the identity theorem like this.

The identity theorem works if the set $S$ where $f=g$ is a subset of the domain $D$, where $D$ has to be open.
This is not possible here, because with $S=\partial \mathbb D$ $S$ is not a subset of the domain $\mathbb D$,
and choosing $D=\overline{\mathbb D}$ is impossible because it is not open.

The maximum modulus principle is a good hint.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you tell me how to apply the maximum modulus principle in order to understand it better..